# Change Timer interval value on the fly

Tags: c#

I have a CSV file that will read LineByLine ... like :

> 0
>   2.25
>   5
>   5.30

I need to Timer interval to change ... but there is no effect when its changed...
I need to fill a textbox.

please let me know your solution

```
while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] temp = currentLine.Split(',');

    timerinterval = (int)(Convert.ToDouble(temp[0])*1000);
    if ((int)(Convert.ToDouble(temp[0]) * 1000) != 0)
    {
        mytimer.Stop();
        mytimer.Interval = (int)(Convert.ToDouble(temp[0]) * 1000);
        mytimer.Start();
        txtCurrentLine.Text = currentLine;
        txtTime.Text = timerinterval.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to increase the time as the file is being read, or reflect the value in the file?

Comment: So what is your timer doing?

Comment: how do you know there is no effect? Did you look to see what timerINterval actually contains?

Comment: there are no ',' in the sample input you show, but you split on ','

Answer (score 0):

```
    public TimeCapture
    {
         public TimeCapture() => Start = DateTime.Now;

         public Start { get; }

         public TimeSpan Duration => DateTime.Now.Subtract(Start).Value.TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Then when you intend to read each line.

```
var timer = new TimeCapture();
while(...)
{
    ... 
    txtTime.Text = timer.Duration;
}
```

Now as you iterate every single line you're capturing the duration as it is reading each line.  If you are interested in line by line duration, simply create a new object per line, then put duration and it'll be for the linear code block.